# AWS Elastic Beanstalk, create environment failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, github

I am using EB for the first time, attempting to upload a Ruby on Rails application from Github to AWS. I am following the step-by-step guide, but I continue running into an error:

```
$ eb create betz5-env
Creating application version archive "app-7f74-160822_083029".
Uploading betz/app-7f74-160822_083029.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
Environment details for: betz5-env
Application name: betz
Region: us-east-1
Deployed Version: app-7f74-160822_083029
Environment ID: e-3zyk4pueyq
Platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.3 running Ruby 2.1 (Puma)
Tier: WebServer-Standard
CNAME: UNKNOWN
Updated: 2016-08-22 12:29:03.932000+00:00
Printing Status:
INFO: createEnvironment is starting.
INFO: Using elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-167880342437 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
INFO: Created security group named: sg-9e6fc9e4
INFO: Created load balancer named: awseb-e-3-AWSEBLoa-6TCKNDPQOZUO
INFO: Environment health has transitioned to Pending. Initialization in progress (running for 32 seconds). There are no instances.
INFO: Created security group named: awseb-e-3zyk4pueyq-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-1VXHTSO3R625H
INFO: Created Auto Scaling launch configuration named: awseb-e-3zyk4pueyq-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-CI7ZCOZGHSI
INFO: Added instance [i-03e33a1f265f89c11] to your environment.
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-3zyk4pueyq-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1CN3N9XS45D1M
INFO: Waiting for EC2 instances to launch. This may take a few minutes.
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:167880342437:scalingPolicy:67c04326-a636-4870-ad45-b90a1b436646:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-3zyk4pueyq-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1CN3N9XS45D1M:policyName/awseb-e-3zyk4pueyq-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleUpPolicy-TKX4L47COQH7
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:167880342437:scalingPolicy:87478c0b-452a-46ab-a23a-4434d4138a10:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-3zyk4pueyq-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1CN3N9XS45D1M:policyName/awseb-e-3zyk4pueyq-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleDownPolicy-1UGEJG8FXVJPC
INFO: Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-3zyk4pueyq-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmLow-BA27Q69FXPNG
INFO: Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-3zyk4pueyq-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh-13NTHLWPMZE13
ERROR: [Instance: i-03e33a1f265f89c11] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)... denied for user 'root'@'ec2-54-204-93-56.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.9/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.9/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace). 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/12_db_migration.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.
WARN: Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Degraded. Command failed on all instances. Initialization completed 39 seconds ago and took 6 minutes.

ERROR: The operation timed out. The state of the environment is unknown. The timeout can be set using the --timeout option.
```

I realize that I am leaving this quite open-ended, but I have no idea why this is not working or what my next step should be to resolve it.  The AWS trouble-shooting docs do not seem to be on point, from what I have been able to find.  Thanks for any help.

Here is the eb-activity log: https://github.com/newom/betz/issues/1

Comment: Can you add /var/log/eb-activity.log content to the question

Comment: Can you check your ```database.yml``` for proper settings?

Comment: added the eb-activity log.

I did not change database.yml settings, i was unaware that I had to.  I am currently using mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following commands into the *.config file

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATIONS
    value: true
```